# Remove end users ability to sort upon a column

Tags: r, dt

I have a large datatables object and I want to limit the sortability of certain columns. I think I have to use the options argument, but my knowledge of JavaScript is not at the point where I know how to integrate it with arguments of a function.

I have the following code as an example:

```
library(DT)

# Create Columns and dataframe
letters <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
numbers <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
words <- c("the", "quick", "brown", "fox")
df <- data.frame(letters, numbers, words, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Create Data Table
htmlDf <- datatable(df, rownames = FALSE)
```

I also have the following code snippet that I have tried to massage into the options argument. The small code chunk came from https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderable.

```
    $('#example').dataTable( {
      "columns": [
        {null,
         "orderable": false },
         null,
                ]
    } );
```

For the purpose of this question, suppose I wish to remove the ability to sort on the "numbers" column.

Thanks!

Note: this is not for a Shiny App.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [site for the R package `DT`](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html) provides some great tutorials on how to convert the javascript options from `datatables` into R syntax.

Essentially what you do is pass nested, named lists which mirror the structure of the JavaScript code into the `options` argument for the `datatable` function. So in your case, you'd want to do this:

```
htmlDf <- datatable(df,
                    rownames = FALSE,
                    options = list(
                        columnDefs = list(
                            list(orderable = F,
                                 targets = c(1))
                            )
                        )
                    )
```

Which nicely applies the `orderable = FALSE` condition to column 1. Note that you have to use JavaScript style 0-indexing rather than R style 1-indexing:

[image]